# How can I sort and reduce the object base on this sample data from javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The date and time are integers, I would like to sort and reduce them base on up to date format like date should be up to date and military time should be up to date too. All values are distinct base on there object id

```js
let arr = [
            {"id": 1, "date": 20220518, "time": 1700},
            {"id": 1, "date": 20220518, "time": 1500},
            {"id": 1, "date": 20220518, "time": 2200},
            {"id": 1, "date": 20220517, "time": 2300},
            {"id": 2, "date": 20220518, "time": 1500},
            {"id": 2, "date": 20220516, "time": 2100},
            {"id": 3, "date": 20220518, "time": 1400},
            {"id": 3, "date": 20220517, "time": 1900},
            {"id": 3, "date": 20220518, "time": 1900},
            {"id": 4, "date": 20220517, "time": 1900},
            {"id": 4, "date": 20220516, "time": 1300},
            {"id": 5, "date": 20220516, "time": 1600}
        ]
    
    
    
 // Result should be like this
 let arr = [
            {"id": 1, "date": 20220518, "time": 2200},
            {"id": 2, "date": 20220518, "time": 1500},
            {"id": 3, "date": 20220518, "time": 1900},
            {"id": 4, "date": 20220517, "time": 1900},
            {"id": 5, "date": 20220516, "time": 1600}
        ]
```

Comment: What you have done so far, can you please pst the code you tried

Answer (score 1):

#### Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 1, date: 20220518, time: 1700 },
  { id: 1, date: 20220518, time: 1500 },
  { id: 1, date: 20220518, time: 2200 },
  { id: 1, date: 20220517, time: 2300 },
  { id: 2, date: 20220518, time: 1500 },
  { id: 2, date: 20220516, time: 2100 },
  { id: 3, date: 20220518, time: 1400 },
  { id: 3, date: 20220517, time: 1900 },
  { id: 3, date: 20220518, time: 1900 },
  { id: 4, date: 20220517, time: 1900 },
  { id: 4, date: 20220516, time: 1300 },
  { id: 5, date: 20220516, time: 1600 },
];
const result = arr.filter(
  (item) =>
    !arr.some(
      (i) =>
        i.id === item.id &&
        // assume the time is a 4 digits number
        i.date * 10000 + i.time > item.date * 10000 + item.time
    )
);

console.log(result);
```

#### Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let arr = [
      { id: 1, date: 20220518, time: 1700 },
      { id: 1, date: 20220518, time: 1500 },
      { id: 1, date: 20220518, time: 2200 },
      { id: 1, date: 20220517, time: 2300 },
      { id: 2, date: 20220518, time: 1500 },
      { id: 2, date: 20220516, time: 2100 },
      { id: 3, date: 20220518, time: 1400 },
      { id: 3, date: 20220517, time: 1900 },
      { id: 3, date: 20220518, time: 1900 },
      { id: 4, date: 20220517, time: 1900 },
      { id: 4, date: 20220516, time: 1300 },
      { id: 5, date: 20220516, time: 1600 },
    ];
const result = arr.reduce((previousArray, currentItem) => {
  const item = previousArray.find((i) => i.id === currentItem.id);
  if (item) {
    if (currentItem.date > item.date) {
      item.date = currentItem.date;
      item.time = currentItem.time;
    } else if (currentItem.date === item.date && currentItem.time > item.time) {
      item.time = currentItem.time;
    }
  } else {
    previousArray.push(currentItem);
  }
  return previousArray;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You'll improve your chances of up-votes and acceptance if you make the code runnable via a snippet. Just a suggestion

Comment: @KScandrett Good suggestion! I don't know there is a snippet feature. I'm going to look into how to use it. Will update the answer later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways I don't know about your data and what you have done so far. Simple logic is below you can filter the data as below or you can use jquery.

If you want to sort the array then sort it before re-creating.

```js
//Raw data
let arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": 20220518,
    "time": 1700
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": 20220518,
    "time": 1500
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": 20220518,
    "time": 2200
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": 20220517,
    "time": 2300
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": 20220518,
    "time": 1500
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": 20220516,
    "time": 2100
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": 20220518,
    "time": 1400
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": 20220517,
    "time": 1900
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": 20220518,
    "time": 1900
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "date": 20220517,
    "time": 1900
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "date": 20220516,
    "time": 1300
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": 20220516,
    "time": 1600
  }
];

// Sort before creating the data
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.date >= b.date) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.time >= b.time) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
});


//Create the new array with required data
let data = [];
arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  data[e.id] = e;
});
console.log(data.filter(n => n));
```

Comment: He is looking to get the max object based on date+time. In your result, for id:1, is not the max date+tiem combination.

Comment: Ah, you are right he can pass the condition if else.

Comment: id 1 should be 2200